Trigger an action with change in paths AND a tag is pushed
I am trying to write a GitHub action that should trigger when provided paths are updated AND a tag is pushed.
The Github docs suggests, if tags, and paths are provided, tags takes precidence.
I am trying to make this work with a logical AND like this:
name: ci
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'dir1'
    tags:
      - 'v*'
      ...

With the above code, the action gets triggered even if there is an update to some other dir and a tag is pushed.
I've tried the following as well, but is not working as expected.
name: ci
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'dir1'
...

jobs:
  push-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: push
        if: "startsWith(github.ref, 'refs.tags/v')"
        <Push artifact>

And by using dorny/paths-filter action:
name: ci
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
...

jobs:
  push-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check paths
        id: filter
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
        with:
          filters: |
            src:
              - 'dir1'
        
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: push
        if: steps.filter.outputs.src == 'true'
        ...
        <Push artifact>

Can someone please help me achieve this?

When using path filtering you need to watch for any changes inside your dir1 folder:
name: ci
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
...

jobs:
  push-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Check paths
        id: filter
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v3
        with:
          filters: |
            src:
              - 'dir1/**'
      
      - name: push
        if: steps.filter.outputs.src == 'true'
        ...
        <Push artifact>

Otherwise it'll be looking for changes to folder dir1 directly which I don't think it's what you're trying to achieve.

Thanks, I've tried that. While editing I missed the glob pattern in filters.src. Even that didn't work.

What are you seeing when it executes? The job step gets skipped because of the condition?

Even if I make updates to files in some other dir, tag the commit and push it. This workflow still triggers (As tags get precedence over paths).
Am I missing something obvious?

That is the expected result, when you create the tag the workflow triggers and then it should stop as soon as the filtering step returns false. There's no way to make the condition a strict logical AND.

If you want to add a level of encapsulation you can also add a step in your workflow that acts as a filter. So you have a trigger that listens for tags,  use dorny/paths-filter to know what changed and from there trigger the specific workflow attached to the directory, passing the relevant variables.
